# ruby, binary tree size

Tags: ruby

Below is my code. I want to find the size of binary tree. the code so far output a random number.

```
def size
    size=1
    size +=@lchild.size unless @lchild.nil?
    size +=@rchild.size unless @richild.nil?
    size
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this.

```
def size(node)
  if node.nil?
    0
  else
    size(node.left) + 1 + size(node.right)
  end
end
```

.

Comment: `if node.nil?` is slightly unidiomatic -> `if node` (and flip the branches). @John, wasn't your "size" a method?

Comment: Yes, size is a method. I changed the above code little bit. it works